# I am having trouble binding a sprinting action to the shift key in Unreal

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

I am receiving an error code when trying to bind sprinting action to the shift key. The error states, no instance of overloaded functions "UInputComponent::BindAction" matches the argument list.  I am not sure exactly what is wrong but any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

```
// Fill out your copyright notice in the Description page of Project Settings.

#include "Guided_Exercise1.h"
#include "Penmen.h"


// Sets default values
APenmen::APenmen()
{
    // Set this character to call Tick() every frame.  You can turn this off to improve performance if you don't need it.
    PrimaryActorTick.bCanEverTick = true;

    GetCharacterMovement()->JumpZVelocity = 600.f;

    bUseControllerRotationPitch = false;
    bUseControllerRotationYaw = false;
    bUseControllerRotationRoll = false;

    GetCharacterMovement()->bOrientRotationToMovement = true;

    GetCharacterMovement()->MaxWalkSpeed = 5400.f;


}




// Called when the game starts or when spawned
void APenmen::BeginPlay()
{
    Super::BeginPlay();

}

// Called every frame
void APenmen::Tick(float DeltaTime)
{
    Super::Tick(DeltaTime);

}

// Called to bind functionality to input
void APenmen::SetupPlayerInputComponent(UInputComponent* PlayerInputComponent)
{
    Super::SetupPlayerInputComponent(PlayerInputComponent);


    //This code maps the forward, back, right, and left movement to the W, A, S, D keys that were assigned under the details section 
    //of character movement in Unreal.  The values and key information is assigned in the Unreal Engine under Detail of the Character Movement pane
    PlayerInputComponent->BindAxis("MoveForward_Key", this, &APenmen::MoveForward);
    PlayerInputComponent->BindAxis("MoveRight_Key", this, &APenmen::MoveRight);

    //This code makes the character jump by pressing the spacebar
    PlayerInputComponent->BindAction("Jump_Key", IE_Pressed, this, &ACharacter::Jump);
    PlayerInputComponent->BindAction("Jump_Key", IE_Released, this, &ACharacter::StopJumping);

    PlayerInputComponent->BindAction("Run_Key", IE_Pressed, this,  &APenmen::OnStartSprint);
    PlayerInputComponent->BindAction("Run_Key", IE_Released, this, &APenmen::OnEndSprint);

}

//This method makes the character move forward and backward by pressing the W and S key
//which were assigned in the details section of character movement in Unreal
void APenmen::MoveForward(float Value) {

    //UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("W or S Key pressed"));

    const FRotator Rotation = Controller->GetControlRotation();
    const FRotator YawRotation(0, Rotation.Yaw, 0);

    //By using the X axis, the character will now move forward and back.  It will scale along the X axis by moving forward, which
    //has a value of 1.0, and backward, which has a value 0f -1.0.  Visual Studio recieves these values from the Unreal Engine
    const FVector Direction = FRotationMatrix(YawRotation).GetUnitAxis(EAxis::X);

    AddMovementInput(Direction, Value);

}
//This method makes the character move left and right by using the A and S key
void APenmen::MoveRight(float Value) {
    //UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("D or A Key Pressed"));

    const FRotator Rotation = Controller->GetControlRotation();
    const FRotator YawRotation(0, Rotation.Yaw, 0);

    //By using the Y axis, the character will move along the Y axis which is left and right
    const FVector Direction = FRotationMatrix(YawRotation).GetUnitAxis(EAxis::Y);

    AddMovementInput(Direction, Value);
}

void APenmen::OnStartSprint(float Value)
{

    GetCharacterMovement()->MaxWalkSpeed = 5400.f;
}

void APenmen::OnEndSprint(float Value)
{

    GetCharacterMovement()->MaxWalkSpeed = 50.f;

}
```

And here is my .h code:

```
 // Fill out your copyright notice in the Description page of Project Settings.

    #pragma once

    #include "GameFramework/Character.h"
    #include "Penmen.generated.h"

    UCLASS()
    class GUIDED_EXERCISE1_API APenmen : public ACharacter
    {
        GENERATED_BODY()

    public:
        // Sets default values for this character's properties
        APenmen();

    protected:
        void EndSprint();
        // Called when the game starts or when spawned
        virtual void BeginPlay() override;

    public: 
        // Called every frame
        virtual void Tick(float DeltaTime) override;

        // Called to bind functionality to input
        virtual void SetupPlayerInputComponent(class UInputComponent* PlayerInputComponent) override;

        //This sets up the methods for character movement and will grab the Value (1.0 for moving forward and -1.0 for moving backward from Unreal 
        //for how fast to move when the corresponding key is pressed

        void MoveForward(float Value);

        //This sets up the methods for character movement and will grab the Value (1.0 for moving right and -1.0 for moving left from Unreal 
        //for how fast to move when the corresponding key is pressed
        void MoveRight(float Value);

        void OnStartSprint(float Value);

        void OnEndSprint(float Value);





    };
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: good looks ok ,  check spellings for the input bindings

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the declaration of

```
void OnStartSprint(float Value);
void OnEndSprint(float Value);
```

Action callbacks don't take any arguments, as opposed to axis callbacks. This makes sense if you think about the difference between axes and actions. Axes can have a certain value, i.e. how far your thumbstick is pushed. Actions are binary, your button is either pressed or not. So you will need to change the declaration to

```
void OnStartSprint();
void OnEndSprint();
```

Here's a link for further information: https://www.unrealengine.com/blog/input-action-and-axis-mappings-in-ue4